# Post Value Inside of if statement

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a form that submits to itself for validation and has some if statements to display certain classes if there are errors. I am also trying to keep the users post data in the inputs so they don't have to re-type them. I keep getting this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING.`

How do I properly use Post values inside of the if statement?

```php
<?php 
  if ($name_err == 1) 
    echo"<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name*' value='<?php echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>'  class='text error'>";
  else 
    echo "<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name*' class='text'>"; 
?>
```

Comment: FYI, there's no space between the first **echo** and the opening double quote. I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem, but I didn't feel that was something that should be fixed in a formatting edit, so I'm letting you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have you got php tags in the middle of PHP code? That is your mistake. There might be an error for not putting a space after `echo`, cant be sure about though!

```
<?php if ($name_err == 1) echo 

  "<input type='text' 
    name='name' 
    placeholder='Name*' 
    value={$_POST['first_name']}
    class='text error'>";

else echo 

"<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name*' class='text'>"; ?>
```

Comment: To post the users input data after the form is submitted if there is an error so they don't have to re-enter it.

Comment: @tonjaggart you didnt get me, I meant that you are in the middle of open PHP tags anyway!

Comment: I am no longer getting the error but the submitted data does not stay in the input if there is an error here is the new value value='{$_POST['name']}'

Comment: Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

you have a simple parse error.

you are opening a < ? php block inside an active < ?php echo statement.

```
<?php if ($name_err == 1) 
{
    echo "<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name*' value='";
    echo $_POST['first_name'];
    echo "'  class='text error'>";
 }
 else echo "<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name*' class='text'>"; 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($name_err == 1):?>
<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name*' value='<?=$_POST['first_name'];?>'  class='text error'>
<?php else:?>
<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name*' class='text'>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You should close the PHP tag once you don't need PHP anymore, instead of nesting opened PHP tags

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name*' value='<?=$name_err == 1 ? $_POST['first_name'] : '';?>'  class='text <?=$name_err == 1 ? error : ''?>'>
```